# Restarting Couchbase inside a Docker container

Tags: docker, couchbase, clocker

I'm currently trying to run Couchbase Server under CoreOS + Docker using instructions from this [blog
post](http://tleyden.github.io/blog/2014/12/15/running-a-sync-gateway-cluster-under-coreos-on-aws/), and running into a problem. If I run `fleetctl stop couchbase-server` followed by `fleetctl start couchbase-server`, it's losing it's
configuration data which is stored in `/opt/couchbase`, and so it is unable
to rejoin the cluster when it comes back up.

I saw that there was a [yaml config](https://github.com/brooklyncentral/clocker/blob/master/examples/src/main/assembly/files/blueprints/couchbase.yaml) for Couchbase under [Clocker](http://clocker.io/), and wanted to compare to the way it was being done on Clocker to hopefully find a solution.

If I run a Couchbase Server cluster node under Clocker, can nodes be restarted and rejoin the cluster?

Also, which Dockerfile is using for building the docker image that's used?